# Getting "stack trace but never released" and Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a picture in Firebase storage through a real phone. It perfectly works on the Android Studio emulator. However, on a real phone it does not.

I get the following error:

```
E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
          java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
              at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:180)
              at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:181)
              at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$2.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:953)
              ....
```

They are referring to this line in  `AvatarActivity` class:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor fd;
                try {
//the line below///
                    fd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageReturnedIntent.getData(), "r");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
```

What is wrong with this piece of code? It works on my emulator. I tried looking up for solutions but I am not able to fix it.
Thanks

EDIT from Review Queue:

The author states in information posted as an Answer (that may be deleted) that the problem described above was due to connection difficulties.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire method or function where this code lives.

Comment: @CindyMeister I think you should add that as a comment, instead of an edit